# Object.create() not fully creating;

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

Here is the code:

```
//Note: x actually isn't defined, I'm pulling it from an external source

var x = [{ name: 'Michael Lovesllamas Lankford',
 created: 1338420951.11,
 laptop: 'pc',
 laptop_version: null,
 userid: '4fc6aed7eb35c14ad6000057',
 acl: 0,
 fans: 1,
 points: 5,
 avatarid: 34 }]

global.UserBase = {
 userid: -1,
 name: "noidea",
 isSuperUser: false,
 isDJ: false,
 laptop: "pc",
 afkWarned: false,
 afkTime: Date.now(),
 droppedTime: null,
 droppedRoom: null,
 songCount: 0,
 mWaitingSongLimit: 0,
 totalSongCount: 0,
 totalHeartCount: 0,
 totalHeartsGiven: 0,
 customGreeting: null,
 bootAfterSong: false,
 joinedTime: Date.now(),
 whiteList: false,
 allowedToReserveSpot: true
};

global.mUsers = {length:0};

global.Register = function(a) {
 for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  var sUser = a[i];
  mUsers[sUser.userid] = CreateUser(sUser);
  mUsers.length++;
 }
};

global.CreateUser = function(a) {
 var b = Object.create(UserBase);
 b.userid = a.userid;
 b.name = a.name;
 b.laptop = a.laptop;
 if (a.acl > 0) b.isSuperUser = true;
 return b;
};

Register(x);
```

Now, to the problem. Instead of mUsers[sUser.userid] becoming this:

```
'4fc6aed7eb35c14ad6000057': {
 userid: "4fc6aed7eb35c14ad6000057",
 name: "noidea",
 isSuperUser: false,
 isDJ: false,
 laptop: "pc",
 afkWarned: false,
 afkTime: Date.now(),
 droppedTime: null,
 droppedRoom: null,
 songCount: 0,
 mWaitingSongLimit: 0,
 totalSongCount: 0,
 totalHeartCount: 0,
 totalHeartsGiven: 0,
 customGreeting: null,
 bootAfterSong: false,
 joinedTime: Date.now(),
 whiteList: false,
 allowedToReserveSpot: true
}
```

it becomes this:

```
'4fc6aed7eb35c14ad6000057': { 
 userid: '4fc6aed7eb35c14ad6000057',
 name: 'Michael Lovesllamas Lankford',
 laptop: 'pc' 
}
```

Any ideas why the rest of the values in UserBase aren't being added to the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) creates a new object and sets its `prototype` to the object you pass in.

Your object *is* getting initialized, but you're only explicitly setting a few properties on the new object instance.  The properties from the prototype object (`UserBase`) are all accessible, but a direct `console.log` of the object won't print them.

E.g.  after running your code, doing:

```
for(var p in mUsers['4fc6aed7eb35c14ad6000057']) {
  console.log(p, mUsers['4fc6aed7eb35c14ad6000057'][p]);
}
```

prints out:

```
userid 4fc6aed7eb35c14ad6000057
name Michael Lovesllamas Lankford
laptop pc
isSuperUser false
isDJ false
afkWarned false
afkTime 1340089066700
droppedTime null
droppedRoom null
songCount 0
mWaitingSongLimit 0
totalSongCount 0
totalHeartCount 0
totalHeartsGiven 0
customGreeting null
bootAfterSong false
joinedTime 1340089066700
whiteList false
allowedToReserveSpot true
```

Comment: Okay, I just tested, and it worked. Silly me. However, can I still access it via mUsers[var].songCount for example? And I wonder how it will work if I save it to the db. (I'm using couchdb to store these objects)

Comment: Yeah, you can access the properties directly.  Try calling `JSON.stringify` on the object - that's likely what whatever you're using to access couchdb will use.

Comment: I decided to just make the function CREATE an object from scratch rather than use a template, so b = {}; b.userid = userid; and so on. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

`UserBase` is on `global` object, and you need to call `Register` on `global` object.

```
global.CreateUser = function(a) {
 var b = Object.create(this.UserBase);
 b.userid = a.userid;
 b.name = a.name;
 b.laptop = a.laptop;
 if (a.acl > 0) b.isSuperUser = true;
 return b;
};

global.Register(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is happening beacause you are only initializing the values for
userid,
name and laptop.
see your code:

```
b.userid = a.userid;
b.name = a.name;  
b.laptop = a.laptop;
```

to get the desired result, you need to call Global.Register(x) instead of Register(x)